# AWS RDS What is the best practice to keep the staging database up to date with production database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, relational-database, amazon-rds

Is there any best practice to keep the staging database up to date with the production database?

For example,
every day at midnight, the production database overwrites the staging database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the task as said by @John, but there are a few points which we can not know, such as

- the status of the clone
- notification once complete

Below official Blog will help with everything we need to know during every clone.

**Blog:** [Orchestrating database refreshes for Amazon RDS and Amazon Aurora | AWS Database Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/orchestrating-database-refreshes-for-amazon-rds-and-amazon-aurora/)

**CloudFormation Git Repo:** [aws-samples
/
database-refresh-orchestrator-for-amazon-rds-and-amazon-aurora](https://github.com/aws-samples/database-refresh-orchestrator-for-amazon-rds-and-amazon-aurora)

**[Optional] Migrate from RDS to Aurora**
[Migrating an RDS for MySQL snapshot to Aurora - Amazon Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Migrating.RDSMySQL.Import.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to make the Staging database an exact copy of the Production database, then you could:

- Take a **Snapshot** of the Production database
- **Delete** the Staging database
- **Restore** a new Staging database from the Snapshot of the Production database

These steps can be automated via a script that calls the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). For example, it could use:

- `aws rds create-db-snapshot`
- `aws rds delete-db-instance`
- `aws rds restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot`

Comment: Do I have to set up Cron or something to execute these commands?

Comment: My recommendation is to create a script with the appropriate commands. Once you have tested it successfully, then you could schedule the script via `cron`.

Comment: instead of `cron`, there is another AWS service called "AWS System Manager", which can be helpful for all types of `cron` or `windows scheduler task.`

Comment: You could instead code it into an AWS Lambda function (using your preferred programming language) and then schedule the function to run once a day.